# If I have a table with only an auto-increment column, how do I insert into it?

Tags: sql-server, insert, auto-increment

A colleague asked me, if you have a table in SQL Server with only an auto-increment column, how do you insert a new row into that table?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable() VALUES()
```

...doesn't work.

As for why... I'm not really sure.  But I found the question kind of compelling.

Comment: See question [Syntax for INSERTing into a table with no values?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2148091/905686)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
insert into mytable default values
```

Answer (score 2):

Apparently this works:

```
INSERT INTO MyTable DEFAULT VALUES
```

(Just discovered it after I hit Ask Question.  Sorry!)

Answer (score 2):

use default values, works also with defaults

```
create table #test (id int identity, Somedate datetime default getdate())


insert #test default values

select * from #test
```

id  Somedate

1   2009-06-30 16:04:03.307

Answer (score 0):

```
set identity_insert MyTable ON

insert MyTable(MyIdentColumn) values(42)

set identity_insert MyTable OFF
```

Comment: Interesting approach.  It might work better if you replace 42 with something that calculates the next auto-increment value, like MAX(id) + 1.

Comment: calculating the max+1 would defeat the purpose of inserting an explicit value into an identity column.  The 42 was just there as an example - you'd plug whatever value you were trying to insert there.  If you just wanted the max, you wouldn't use my example at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the IDENTITY_INSERT Setting:

SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable ON
INSERT INTO MyTable (AutoIncrementColumnName, OtherColumnNames...)
VALUES (9999, OtherData...)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyTable OFF

Make sure you insert a value that isn't in the key already.