# Syntax for INSERTing into a table with no values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

I have a table created with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Visualizations]
(
    VisualizationID     int identity (1,1)      NOT NULL
)
```

Since the table has no settable fields, I'm not sure how to insert a record. I tried:

```
INSERT INTO [Visualizations];
INSERT INTO [Visualizations] () VALUES ();
```

Neither work. What is the proper syntax to do this?

**Edit:** Since a number of people seem confused by my table, it is used purely to represent a parent of a number of sub-tables... each one references this table by FK and each of those FKs are PKs, so that across all of those tables, the IDs are unique.

Comment: Your table makes a perfect sense.

Comment: It's not difficult to think of other tables where an insertion with default values only makes sense, here's the one that led me here: `CREATE TABLE run (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, start_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,  end_time TIMESTAMP)`. Of course, when my application starts a run, I have to insert a record with default values, and update `end_time` when it ends.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933206(SQL.80).aspx) (example "F. Load data using the DEFAULT VALUES option"):

```
INSERT INTO [Visualizations] DEFAULT VALUES;
```

Comment: Beautifully simple … new link [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#d-inserting-data-into-a-table-with-columns-that-have-default-values).

Comment: Works in SQLite too.

Comment: Works in Postgres too

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on MariaDB (and possibly MySQL) =(

Comment: But apparently the more intuitive `INSERT INTO foo () VALUES ();` works on MySQL and MariaDB =].

Answer (score -3):

Trigger the identity insert with null

```
insert into
            Visualizations
values
           (null);
```

Comment: In SQL Server, using TSQL, this statement gives an error:  "DEFAULT or NULL are not allowed as explicit identity values."

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you need to add a dummy column to do this, and just insert `NULL` into it, the dummy column would allow for NULLs. Although your table structure does not make sense, I would suggest this in order for it to work.