# SQLite Insert with all default values

Tags: android, sqlite

My SQL Structure has 3 elements, all with default values.

```
    "create table " + TB_NAME +
            " (" +
                INDEX + " integer DEFAULT 0," +
                SWATCH + " text DEFAULT ''," +
                COLOR_INDEX + "  integer DEFAULT 0" +
            ");"
```

Needless to say, what is the INSERT call when there aren't any parameters?

Comment: What would be the point of storing a row with just defaults?

Comment: The answer was using the "default values" command. [See here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2148091/syntax-for-inserting-into-a-table-with-no-values